# Why can I install this Jelastic manifest through the dashboard import function but not throuhg the Jelastic API?

Tags: manifest, jelastic

I have the following very simple manifest:

```yaml
type: install
name: very simple manifest

onInstall:
  - log: installing manifest
```

I can install it from the Jelastic Dashboard. There is an import function in the main menu where I can copy / paste that manifest content and it gets installed. In the Jelastic console, I can see

```
[15:36:38 manifest.settings]: BEGIN INSTALLATION: very simple manifest
[15:36:39 manifest.settings]: BEGIN HANDLE EVENT: {"topic":"application/install","envAppid":""}
[15:36:39 manifest.settings:1]:> installing manifest
[15:36:39 manifest.settings]: END HANDLE EVENT: application/install
[15:36:39 manifest.settings]: END INSTALLATION: very simple manifest
```

and the Jelastic dashboard confirms installation.

Now, when I do the same, but via the Jelastic REST API, i.e. using the endpoint

```
http://my-jelastic-provide.com/1.0/marketplace/jps/REST/install
```

with the relevant data, then, it doesn't install. Instead, I get the strange error message

```
Can\'t find environment by domain [jelasticclient-master-0954606]
```

where `jelasticclient-master-0954606` is the `envName` I set.

However, if I change my manifest to e.g.

```yaml
type: install
name: very simple manifest

nodes:
  count: 1
  cloudlets: 4
  nodeGroup: cp
  image: alpine:latest
skipNodeEmails: true

onInstall:
  - log: installing manifest
```

then it installs perfectly. What am I missing?

I am using Jelastic v6.0.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "very simple manifest" doesn't suppose any environment name to be passed.
That's why when you pass it you get an error "Can't find environment by domain [domain-name]" (Example1).

When you **don't** have the "nodes" parameter in the manifest (as in your second example), you shouldn't pass any environment name (Example2) or should pass the existing environment name (response is in Example3).

Example1:

```
curl -X POST 'https://jca.host-domain/1.0/marketplace/jps/rest/install' \
-d 'envName=jelasticclient-master-0954606' \
-d session=*** \    
-d skipNodeEmails=1 \
-d ownerUid=UID \
--data-urlencode 'jps={ "type": "install", "name": "very simple manifest", "onInstall": [ { "log": "installing manifest" } ] }'
```

The response is:

```
{"result":11,"response":{"result":11,"source":"JEL","error":"domain [jelasticclient-master-0954606] doesn't exist"},"source":"JEL","error":"domain [jelasticclient-master-0954606] doesn't exist"}
```

When the environment name is not passed (Example2),

```
curl -X POST 'https://jca.host-domain/1.0/marketplace/jps/rest/install' \
-d session=*** \    
-d skipNodeEmails=1 \
-d ownerUid=UID \
--data-urlencode 'jps={ "type": "install", "name": "very simple manifest", "onInstall": [ { "log": "installing manifest" } ] }'
```

the response is

```
{"result":0,"uniqueName":"3c819586-2ef7-4691-9faa-d3059459d20e","response":{"result":0,"uniqueName":"3c819586-2ef7-4691-9faa-d3059459d20e","successText":"","appid":""},"appid":"","successText":""}
```

When the environment with envName=jelasticclient-master-0954606 already exists, the response of the same request from the Example1 is as this (Example3)

```
{"result":0,"uniqueName":"b52a8db9-8850-4b66-958a-3dee3345b923","response":{"result":0,"uniqueName":"b52a8db9-8850-4b66-958a-3dee3345b923","successText":"","appid":"7b0c465f6c9573b8d8ce3ed59591781b"},"appid":"7b0c465f6c9573b8d8ce3ed59591781b","successText":""}
```

In other words, if you pass the environment name when deploying this "very simple manifest"  this manifest is installed like an add-on because there is no "nodes" parameter in it but there is no existing environment "jelasticclient-master-0954606" to install this "add-on".

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I did not suspect that problem in my manifest installation!